# PHP Simple Dom HTML - Trouble parsing list of a hrefs

Tags: php, html, dom

I'm trying to scrape all the a hrefs with an id starting with 'system' from this webpage: http://www.myfxbook.com/systems

Here is my code which I just can't seem to get to work. I've been fiddling around for hours now, looking at countless answered questions here.

```
    include_once( 'simple_html_dom.php' );  
    $url2process = 'http://www.myfxbook.com/systems';
    $html = file_get_html( $url2process );
    $cnt = 0;
    $parent_mark = $html->find('a[id^=system]');

    $cntr = 0;

    foreach( $parent_mark as $element) {

        if( $cntr > 3 ) continue;
        $cntr++;

        $single_html = file_get_html( $element->href );
```

**UPDATE1:** Ok this is kind of working now, but it only seems to be using the very last a href on the page with the correct id. I need to process ALL these a hrefs with this ID, what am I missing here?

Comment: Did you use the domdocument approach or the Simple HTML Parser?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using the domdocument like this..

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.myfxbook.com/systems');
$doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML($html);
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);
$links = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');
$cnt = 0;
$cntr = 0;
foreach ($links as $link) {
    if(preg_match('~^system~', $link->getAttribute('id'))) {
        if( $cntr > 3 ) {
            continue;
        }
        $cntr++;
        $single_html = file_get_contents($link->getAttribute('href'));
        if (empty($single_html)) {
            echo 'EMPTY'; 
        }
    }
}
```